# Minimal hardware requirements ESP32 WROOM

Tags: pcb, design

I've had a very simple PCB designed to supply the ESP32 WROOM module with power using a voltage regulator that supplies it with 3.3V.

However, this does not seem to be enough to run the firmware application I loaded to it before hand.

Reading from [the docs](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/wiki/ESP32-Boot-Mode-Selection) It tells me GPIO 0 should be high by default when not connected (which it is not.) However when I measure it is at 1.4V (floating)

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about IO0's behavior(breaking chip is possible), but I think you forgot to pull up EN pin.

Pull up it like this.

[image]

You can see the entire image in [official datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-wroom-32_datasheet_en.pdf). It is captioned as "Figure 4: ESP32-WROOM-32 Peripheral Schematics".